# Cartesian product of large sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

For a non-empty set $A$ let $A'$ denote the Cartesian product of $A$ with itself taken denumerably many times.

Now given a set $S$ whose cardinality is strictly greater than the cardinality of continuum (i.e., $\Bbb R$), in which cases do we have ${\rm card}(S')={\rm card}(S)$ and in which cases do we have ${\rm card}(S')\ne{\rm card}(S)$?

Comment: To put things in simpler terms, given a cardinal $\kappa$, you are asking when $\kappa^\omega=\kappa$. The simplest observation is that not every $\kappa\geq2^{\aleph_0}$ has this property. For example $\kappa=\beth_\omega$ is much larger than the continuum but $\kappa^\omega>\kappa$ by Koenig's theorem.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila:- Hm , and when does$\kappa^\omega=\kappa$ hold with $\kappa>2^{\aleph_0}$ ?

Comment: For example when $\kappa=\beth_n$ for $1<n<\omega$, and more. Cardinal arithmetics have two parts in $\sf ZFC$: Boring (addition and multiplication are the same as taking maximum) and insane (cardinal exponentiation has very little beyond Koenig's lemma provable in $\sf ZFC$). You can provably show that at least a few more cardinals after the continuum you will still have this property, but I'm not sure how much further you can keep up with that. In particular, I'm not sure if you can continue this past the first limit cardinal above the continuum (where this property must fail).

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading Lang's algebra?On Page 893 of GTM211, Exercise 13.Lang remarked that the grapevine communicates to him that according to Solovay,the answer is "card S does not always equal to card S'."Maybe you can refer to Solovay's research to find the answer.
I hope this is helpful to you.